# MFC - Printing rtf document

Tags: mfc

How to print a RTF document in a MFC application without displaying it?

The user will go through the following step to print the file:
1. Choose the rtf file.
2. A print dialog box will appear after that
3. Press OK to print the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it in an invisible CRichEditCtrl and pass a printer DC when sending WM_PRINT to the window.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide me with a simple example how to do this?

Comment: In fact using FormatRange to print. Example at http://www.codersource.net/forums/173/ShowPost.aspx.